# How to remove data from another data array that already existed in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to remove data from another data array that already existed.

for example:

```
data = [{
 name: "james",
 device: "device1"
}, {
 name: "justine",
 device: "device2"
}];

device = [
 'device1', 'device2', 'device3', 'device4', 'device5'
];
```

how to remove the device that already exist?

expected output:

```
device = ['device3', 'device4', 'device5'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get an array of the "existing" devices from your data structure:

```
const usedDevices = data.map((el) => el.device)
```

Then, filter all devices by checking if they are in your `usedDevices` list

```
const remaining = device.filter((el) => usedDevices.indexOf(el) < 0)
```

There you go:

```
console.log(remaining)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
const data = [{name:"james",device:"device1"},{name:"justine",device:"device2"}];
let device = ["device1","device2","device3","device4","device5"];

// Get all the devices to be removed first
var remove = data.map(({device}) => device)

// Delete the above devices which are present in device array
// using filter() method
device = device.filter(d => !remove.includes(d));

console.log(device)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```